# I couldn't remove border from my table on my WP site

Tags: html, css

I can not hide the border around the table. I have used hungarian IDs and picture names but id doesn't matter I think, the JS works well. I can not hide it, but i can make it bigger than 0px.

I have tried `!important`, `border: none`, `border: 0px`, or simple tried to change it to white.

```
#tablazat {
    border-bottom: 0px solid blue;
}



<table id="tablazat">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <img onclick="kep1('inferno')" class="mapok" id="inferno" src="http://www.mathiaszlan.nhely.hu/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/inferno.png" disabled="true"></th>
            <th>
                <img onclick="kep1('train')" class="mapok" id="train" src="http://www.mathiaszlan.nhely.hu/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/train.png" disabled="true"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <img onclick="kep1('mirage')" class="mapok" id="mirage" src="http://www.mathiaszlan.nhely.hu/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/mirage.png" disabled="true"></th>
            <th>
                <img onclick="kep1('nuke')" class="mapok" id="nuke" src="http://www.mathiaszlan.nhely.hu/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/nuke.png" disabled="true"></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: We're not going to be able to help here. Some stylesheet or inline style needs to be overridden. You'll need to use your browser's document inspector to see what it is. It's quite possible that the table row has a border, or that some outer element does.

Comment: If you care to link to the site I'm sure we can help.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or codepen for this?

Comment: Here is a link http://www.mathiaszlan.nhely.hu/bannolas/  and here is a codepen https://codepen.io/Mini0925/pen/yLBPqzZ 
I have to say sorry, i am new at here and i dont know how to show the most information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border is around `th` and `td` element (in your style.css):

```css
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you want to remove it from this specific table you can do that by adding:

```css
#tablazat th {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put this attributes in your table

```
<table id="tablazat" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

Also try to avoid using  element unless you are trying to have a view of something similar to a spreadsheet

Better use  and css flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Instead of below code

```
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

you can use

```
th, td {
    border: 0px solid #333;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
 }
```